# Catch any excpetion to avoid memory leak - Python bad/good pratices

Tags: python, exception, decorator

I want to make sure a method is called if any exception is raised. In this situation, is it ok (good/bad practices or may lead to unexpected consequences) to `try/except` any Exception? Here's an example of what's on my mind using a decorator:

```py
# implementation
import sys
import traceback


class AmazingClass:

  def __init__(self, arg=None):
    self.__att = arg

  @property
  def att(self, ):
    return self.__att

  def make_sure_it_quits(method):

    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
      try:
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      except Exception as err:
        print(err, "- This was caught because it couldn't be foreseen.")
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("\nQuitting what is suppose to be quited...")
        self.quit()

    return inner

  @make_sure_it_quits
  def this_may_raise_errors(self, arg):
    try:
      self.__att += arg
    except TypeError as err:
      print("This I can handle! Cleaning and exiting...")
      self.quit()
      # sys.exit(1)  # exit, if it's the case

  def quit(self, ):
    self.__arg = None
    print("Everything is very clean now!")
```

```py
# examples

def no_errors():
  obj = AmazingClass("test")
  obj.this_may_raise_errors("_01")
  print(obj.att)


def with_error_01():
  obj = AmazingClass("test")
  obj.this_may_raise_erros(1)
  print(obj.att)

def with_error_02():
  obj = AmazingClass("test")
  obj.this_may_raise_errors()
  print(obj.att)
```

```py
# main

if __name__ == '__main__':
  no_errors()
  with_error_01()
  with_error_02()
```

In this case, `with_error_01` represents situations I know in advance that can happen, while `with_error_02` is an unexpected use of the class.

In both cases, the use of `traceback` shows what and where went wrong. Also, the method `quit` must always be called in case of any error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Trapping an error in python](/q/10454868/90527)", "[Bad idea to catch all exceptions in Python](/q/10594113/90527)", "[How can I write a `try`/`except` block that catches all exceptions?](/a/4994509/90527)", "[In Python, will raising an Exception inside of a while loop lead to memory leaks?](/q/60454441/90527)"

Comment: They're all very clarifying, but don't answer my question. Note that I use `traceback`, so in any case, if any exception occur, the user of AmazingClass will know what and where went wrong, right? Also, the object should always call `quit` whenever the decorated method fails for any reason, so terminating the program is often necessary, and not something I'd like to avoid or work around.